# Pass javascript Variable in on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How would I go about doing this?

```
$(document).on('click', "'.span_" + editableObj.textContent + "'", function(e){

}
```

I am getting an error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.span_mytext'
```

Tried many variations and can't get it to work..

Comment: `".span_" + editableObj.textContent`

Comment: `$(document).on('click', ".span_" + editableObj.textContent, function(e){..}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation if you can:

```
$(document).on('click', `.span_${editableObj.textContent}`, function(e){

}
```

Or, if you can, you should concat like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.span_' + editableObj.textContent, function(e){

}
```

Comment: So easy once you lay it all out! Thank you was messing with it for a bit.

Comment: You're safe of downvote because of string interpolation :-)

Comment: @Ele What's wrong with string interpolation? I use it all the time

Comment: Nothing, because of that you're safe of downvotes. +1 from me.

Answer (score -2):

Replace it with.

```
$(document).on('click', ".span_" + editableObj.textContent , 
 function(e){
  // do whatever you want to
 });
```

This will help you

Comment: This is a typo, so you don't need to waste time with this kind of answer.